# What is the best way to do "chmod +x" within Chef

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am trying to run `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/binaryname` within chef.
I have used `execute resource`for that as shown below:

```
execute "run_binary" do
  command "chmod +x binaryname"
  cwd "/usr/local/bin"
  not_if "stat --format=%a /usr/local/bin/binaryname" | grep 755
end
```

Please let me know if there is a better way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a file resource:

```
file '/usr/local/bin/binaryname' do
  mode '755'
end
```

If you don't specify an owner/group/content then Chef doesn't manage those properties.